# why in jquery did developers use confusing inverse over straight forward comparisons

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function grep( elems, callback, invert ) {
        var callbackInverse,
            matches = [],
            i = 0,
            length = elems.length,
            callbackExpect = !invert;

        // Go through the array, only saving the items
        // that pass the validator function
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                callbackInverse = !callback( elems[ i ], i );
                if ( callbackInverse !== callbackExpect ) {
                    matches.push( elems[ i ] );
                }
            }
        return matches;
    }
```

wouldn't this be more straight forward

```
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            callbackInverse = callback( elems[ i ], i );
            if ( callbackInverse == callbackExpect ) {
                matches.push( elems[ i ] );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Programming styles...I use inverses all the time in my day to day, looks nicer than leaving an empty `if` block and only using the `else`

Comment: Or use the `unless` statement with coffeescript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it's to make sure both variables are booleans.

For example, imagine `callback` returns `NaN` when running

```
callbackInverse = callback( elems[ i ], i );
```

That could be problematic, given that

```
NaN == true;  // false
NaN == false; // false
```

(It happens because the comparisson of a boolean and a number coerced the boolean to a number, instead of coercing the number to boolean)

But negating the values with `!` converts them to booleans, avoiding those problems.

Comment: +1 the alternatives to avoid inverting would be to use [`toBoolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToBoolean), or `callbackBool = !!callback( ... ); if ( callbackBool == ...` with `callbackExpect = !!thirdArg`, either of which would probably be more confusing

Answer (score 2):

Note that callbackExpect is set to !invert:

```
callbackExpect = !invert;
```

This forces callbackExpect to be a "boolean" (so exactly `true` or `false`).

Then they compare using `!==` which is not the same as `!=` in that it compares the content of the variable without conversion. In other words, if callbackInverse is not exactly 0 or 1, it returns true.

Note that the inverse of `!==` is `===` and not `==` as in your example. i.e. compare without first converting the parameters.

---

Update:

As pointed out by Walter Tross in a comment, [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a separate type:

```
// Booleans
typeof true === 'boolean';
typeof false === 'boolean';
typeof Boolean(true) === 'boolean'; // but never use this form!
```

Therefore the !invert generates a Boolean and if callbackInverse is not a Boolean, then `!==` is going to be true. However, like the callbackExpect variable, it is set to `!(of something)` which means it will always be a Boolean too. So you could use `==` and `!=` since the `!` operator is used to canonicalize the returned values.

Comment: in JavaScript a boolean is not `0` or `1`, it is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2):

Because this way both the `invert` param and the return value of the `callback` are cast to boolean by the `!`, so that they can be safely compared as booleans.

E.g., imagine `callback` returns `undefined`. But **`undefined != false`**, while you probably want `undefined` to be treated like `false`. In fact, casting it to boolean yields `false`:

`!!undefined === false` (`!!` is an easy way of casting to boolean).

Instead of doing the double negation, jQuery does a single one, negating the other side just once, before the loop, so that the comparison becomes:

`!undefined === !false` (this is a bit like changing the sign of both sides of an equation.)

Quoting the [ECMAScript 5.1 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> Boolean comparison can be forced by: !a == !b.

The price of doing a single negation instead of a double negation inside the loop is readability (which is always impaired when using "negative logic"), but in a highly optimized library like jQuery this is acceptable.

As to your example, you should rename `callbackInverse` to something like `callbackValue`, since it's not inverted (and not cast to boolean) any more. But the problem remains: your code will only work correctly if `callback` is guaranteed to return booleans.